# Ordering sentences with span elements?

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

I really have tried to find an answer but nothing comes close. I want to be able to reorder sentences, i.e. drag and drop them. But I also want them to be editable. Oh, and yes, preferably without jquery or such...

It would work to have e.g. "ctr" key toggle contenteditable if needed to switch between editing and reordering. But I cannot figure out how a drag event can figure out the position to drop it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.sentence1 {color: blue;}
.sentence2 {color: red;}
.sentence3 {color: green;}
</style>
<body>
<div class="paragraph">
<span id="three" class="sentence3" contenteditable="true" >This is really the third sentence.</span>
<span id="one" class="sentence1" contenteditable="true" >This is really the first sentence.</span> 
<span id="two" class="sentence2" contenteditable="true" >This is really the second sentence.</span> 
</div>
```

I thought this might be useful for some if solved so I did not provide more of the code I tried and failed with. Any suggestions most welcome!

Comment: I don't see any draggable code anywhere in your question. What have you tried?

Comment: Give this a good read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Comment: start by messing around with the order property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: Here is a nice guide using html, css and javascript: http://syntaxxx.com/rearranging-web-page-items-with-html5-drag-and-drop/
Not sure how it will work with contenteditable though.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared a little sandbox for you to mess around with. Fiddle link in the bottom.

```
var SPANs = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Control") {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(SPANs, function (item) {
      item.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
    });
  }
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(SPANs, function (item) {
    item.setAttribute("contenteditable", true);
  });
});

Array.prototype.forEach.call(SPANs, function (item) {
  item.addEventListener("drag", function (event) {
    console.log("Moving element");
  }, false);
});
```

[Fiddle with a little piece of JS code](https://jsfiddle.net/vd9oakw4/4/)

Comment: Moving element is possible while holding Control key.

Answer (score 0):

To make something drag & droppable... (this could be fairly long, so just listing the steps, not the code, if someone else has the energy to write it up, won't blame you to make another answer out of it.)

Step 1. Make the div position pop to up z when mouse/touch down, and move position relative to window based on mouse/touch position.

Step 2. Make all potential placement positions listen for on mouseenter or equivalent (often javascript making temporary 1 or 0 height divs between existing ones.) If mouseenters/equivalent, make them active. If mouse/touch leaves, make them inactive.

Step 3a. If mouseup/endtouch while a potential placement div is active, replace it with the span.

Step 3b. If mouseup/endtouch while no potential placement div is active, remove the temp divs and put the picked-up div back where it was.

(Note: Drag javascript isn't supported on a fair number of mobile browsers as of yet. Once it is in a few years, that would probably be bet the better route)

Answer (score 0):

So, this seems quite complicated the way I framed the question above even if its doable.

I think using e.g. [sortable.js](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable) (which is non-jquery) is one avenue.

I have ended up trying to do something using vue instead, the reason being it is easier to keep a data object for sorting and editing and use virtual doms to display as needed when needed. Thanks all for suggestions!